# Insufficient permission while replying to business review through api

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-reviews, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

I have a google account where there are 2 accounts (i.e PERSONAL & LOCATION GROUP).
In  account of type LOCATION GROUP there are multiple location. [accounts information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGeog.png)

I can fetch the locations through the api.
I can fetch the reviews through the api.
[Location Review Fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtZpW.png)

But when i try to reply the review through the api . It gives me insufficient permissions to access the resource.
[Review Reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjY2v.png)

Tried with different locations but the issue is same.

Note::  I tried it with another account and there was no issue updating the reply to the review

1. Tried with multiple location for the same account( Did not worked)
2. Tried with different account and it worked perfectly.

Can anybody help me what permission is not set or anything i am missing.